# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to \sqrt 2}\frac{\sqrt{3+2x} - (\sqrt 2+1)}{x^2-2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I used rationalization trick where you multiply the top and bottom with opposites of given functions and thus got  $\frac{2(x^2+2)}{(x^2-2)({\sqrt {3+2x} + (\sqrt2 + 1)})}$ but by then it has become too complex. The book says answer should be $\frac{1}{2(2+\sqrt 2)}$.

Comment: l'hopital's rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a mistake in the numerator.

\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{3+2x} - (\sqrt 2+1)}{x^2-2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3+2x} + (\sqrt 2+1)}{\sqrt{3+2x} + (\sqrt 2+1)} &= \frac{3+2x - (\sqrt{2}+1)^2}{(x^2-2)(\sqrt{3+2x} + (\sqrt 2+1))}\\
&= \frac{2(x-\sqrt{2})}{(x^2-2)(\sqrt{3+2x} + (\sqrt 2+1))}\\
&= \frac{2}{(x+\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3+2x} + (\sqrt 2+1))}\\
&\xrightarrow{x\to\sqrt{2}} \frac{2}{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2})(2\cdot (\sqrt{2}+1))}\\
&= \frac{1}{2(2+\sqrt2)}
\end{align}

Comment: Ha!! that's why i couldn't compute it further. Thank you.

Comment: hey @mechanodroid but where does the root 3 from the denominator go. Does all of root of (3+2x) get converted to 2.

Comment: @zaidkhan Notice that $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}} = 1+\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: oh.too clever that one

Comment: @zaidkhan: The form of the limit is a clue to check if $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2} = 1+\sqrt2$, since the limit doesn't exist if that's not true.

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, exactly. That's why I assumed the OP already knew that.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the fact that$$\lim_{x\to\sqrt2}\frac{\sqrt{3+2x}-\sqrt2-1}{x^2-2}=\lim_{x\to\sqrt2}\frac{\sqrt{3+2x}-\sqrt2-1}{x-\sqrt2}\times\lim_{x\to\sqrt2}\frac1{x+\sqrt2}.$$The first limit is just the computation of a derivative.

Comment: I assume you mean that $f(x)=\sqrt{3+2x}$ and $f(\sqrt{2}) = \sqrt{2}+1$? But that is not easy to show to be true. It is true, but it is definitely not apparent to me. How did you show that is true?

Comment: Because$$\left(\sqrt2+1\right)^2=2+2\sqrt2+1=3+2\sqrt2=f\left(\sqrt2\right).$$